# Include If Else statement in String.Format

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I have the following statemnt.

```
  timespan = timespan.FromSeconds(236541)
  formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0} hr {1} mm {2} sec", Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours), timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds)
```

I have to have it formatted as "hrs mn sec" if there are more than one hour. I want to check this within the String.Format above.

Thanks.

Comment: Just be lazy and write `"{0} hr(s)..."`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is to make the plural part of the format string, and write:

```
formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0} hr{1} {2} mm {3} sec",
    Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours),
    Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours) == 1 ? "" : "s",
    timespan.Minutes,
    timespan.Seconds);
```

This will insert a "s" into the output if the output says anything other than "1 hr".

Note that this is not friendly to localization: other languages form plurals differently than English.

Comment: I take this as the answer. For cleaner code, I think we should take suggestion from Kobi's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the cleanest way to do this is to write your own [`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx). Here's an example of a convenient pluralizer format:

```
using System;

public class PluralFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {

   public object GetFormat(Type formatType) {
      if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
         return this;
      else
         return null;
   }

   public string Format(string format, object arg, 
                          IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   {   
      if (! formatProvider.Equals(this)) return null;

      if (! format.StartsWith("^")) return null;

      String[] parts = format.Split(new char[] {'^'});
      int choice = ((int) arg) == 1 ? 1 : 2;
      return String.Format("{0} {1}", arg, parts[choice]);
   }

   public static void Main() {
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format(
         new PluralFormatter(),
         "{0:^puppy^puppies}, {1:^child^children}, and {2:^kitten^kittens}", 
         13, 1, 42
      ));
   }
}
```

The output is, as one might've guessed ([and as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/tanLM)):

```
13 puppies, 1 child, and 42 kittens
```

#### MSDN links

- [Custom Formatting with `ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx#Custom)
- [`System.ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx)
- [`System.IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No magic here. Why would you code in whatever condition `format` may offer, when you can code in C#?

To avoid duplicated code, you might as promote some expressions to variables, and use the condition on them:

```
timespan = timespan.FromSeconds(236541);
int hours = Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours);
string hoursUnit = hours == 1 ? "hr" : "hrs";
formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0}{1} {2} mm {3} sec",
                        hours, hoursUnit, timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know this method. My question is that "Can I do it within String.Format?".

Comment: I think you need to include "hours" in the String.Format as well.

Comment: @Angkor Wat - Fixed, Thanks! Must have missed that one when I added the new line `:P`

Answer (score 3):

I use a few extension methods which help me with this sort of thing:

```
public static string Inflect(this string noun, int count)
{
 return (count == 1 || noun.EndsWith("s", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ? noun : noun + "s";
}

public static string Of(this int count, string noun)
{
 return string.Format("{0} {1}", count, noun.Inflect(count));
}
```

e.g.:

`"Hour".Inflect(1)` : Hour

`"Hour".Inflect(2)` : Hours

`0.Of("hour")` : "0 hours"

`1.Of("hour")` : "1 hour"

`5.Of("hour")` : "5 hours"

Comment: I actually have a similar method in use. In fact, I wrote a whole control for that. In Hebrew, it is common to have different nouns for 1 2 or more (think "once, twice, 3 times"). Even for English, it would be more useful with two words: `(2).Of("Memory", "Memories")` - you don't want to rewrite the English Grammar in your code...

Comment: +1 @Kobi: Yes, that would be really useful. 
I normally use this method for just the sort of issue the OP is facing, when I know the noun in question, and that it inflects 'normally'.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the various time format specifiers.  It helps simplify the call to `Format()` immensely.

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(236541);
var formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0:hh} hr{1} {0:mm} mm {0:ss} sec",
    timespan, timespan.Hours != 1 ? "s" : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "simple" way of doing this.

You can either do it like this

```
string templateSingleHour = "{0} hr {1} mm {2} sec";
string templateMultiHour = "{0} hrs {1} mm {2} sec";
string template = Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours) > 1 ? templateMultiHour :templateSingleHour;
formattedTimeSpan = String.Format(template ...)
```

or like this

```
formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0} {3} {1} mm {2} sec", Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours), timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours) > 1 ? "hrs" : "hr");
```

Comment: Why write `Math.Truncate(timespan.TotalHours) > 1` when you can use `timespan.TotalHours >= 2`?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if your app is going to be used my non-english speakers ever then this is something that's not trivial. There is a blog post that expounds on the problem at http://www.siao2.com/2007/07/24/4022881.aspx