# C#: String.Format Can i use "If" statement inside?

Tags: c#, string, forms, conditional-operator

Im creating a C# program that uses String.Format to create a string that show a lot of information from a collected Windows Forms to a textbox. To simplify if-else treatment im thinking in using something like if-else inside String.Format method, such like:

```
result = String.Format("G{0}P{1}C{2}A{3}", 
                       numericUpDown2.Value,
                       numericUpDown3.Value,
                       numericUpDown4.Value,
                       numericUpDown5.Value?>0:numericUpDown5.Value+3);
```

Is that ({3} piece) possible sameway? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use the ternary conditional operator in C#.  What happens when you try?  (Note: You appear to have a typo on your example usage, which the compiler would be indicating to you if that is your attempt.)

Comment: There's a typo in `numericUpDown5.Value?>0:numericUpDown5.Value+3` should be something like `numericUpDown5.Value > 0 ? numericUpDown5.Value : numericUpDown5.Value + 3`. When `numericUpDown5.Value > 0` we print it as it is, when `numericUpDown5.Value` is not positive we add `3` to existsing value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include If Else statement in String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508943/include-if-else-statement-in-string-format)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your ternary operator has a syntax error in it.
Try to exchange it for something like this:

```
numericUpDown5.Value > 0 ? numericUpDown5.Value : numericUpDown5.Value+3
```

More information on the ternary operator can be found on the respective [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, like any other expression would be possible. Note, however, that the `?` should come **after** the condition, and the `:` should be used to separate the "true" branch from the "false" branch:

```cs
result = String.Format("G{0}P{1}C{2}A{3}", 
                       numericUpDown2.Value,
                       numericUpDown3.Value,
                       numericUpDown4.Value,
                       numericUpDown5.Value >0 ? // Condition to evaluate
                        numericUpDown5.Value+3 : // value if the condition if true 
                        numericUpDown5.Value     // value if it isn't
                      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want

- Existing `numericUpDown5.Value` when `Value` is positive
- `Value + 3` when `Value` is negative or zero

You can use ternary operator like this:

Format:

```
result = String.Format("G{0}P{1}C{2}A{3}",  
  numericUpDown2.Value, 
  numericUpDown3.Value, 
  numericUpDown4.Value, 
  numericUpDown5.Value > 0 ? numericUpDown5.Value : numericUpDown5.Value + 3);
```

String interpolation:

```
result = $"G{numericUpDown2.Value}P{numericUpDown3.Value}C{numericUpDown4.Value}A{(numericUpDown5.Value > 0 ? numericUpDown5.Value : numericUpDown5.Value + 3)}";
```

Note that in the last case we should wrap in `(..)` otherwise, `:` will be treated as a format and we have a compile time error.